# Speed up T-SQL CTE by rebuilding only part of the tree you want?

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I have a very simple table of a ParentID (int) and ChildID (int). The problem is that it's several thousand lines long and many of the ChildIDs are the ParentIDs of other ParentIDs.

All I'm interested in is building the hierarchy of all of these shared IDs. However, some branches may only be 2 or 3 levels deep while other may go 30+ levels deep.

While all of the data is important, only certain branches (and their sub-branches) are important at particular times.

My original attempt was to just 'bruteforce' it and build the whole tree, but it's incredibly inefficient and resource intensive.

Therefore, I was wondering how I could tweak my basic very simple/standard CTE (using the aforementioned simple table with only the two integer columns) to pick a particular branch of this very complicated tree and just recursively build the hierarchy of just the branch I want out to it's farthest point without having to build the rest of the tree and all of its branches.

Is this possible?

As a side note - because of the sheer volume of data combined with it's simplicity of only being numeric data, I have no ability to guess what would come after a certain branch (i.e., there is no sequential numbering or anything that provide hints, basically anything could be beyond the branch I want to I know I need to pull from all of the data, I just don't want to have to waste time/resources building branches I don't need).

EDIT: Here is my sample code:

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
Select ChildID
    ,ParentID
    ,cast(ParentID as varchar(max)) as IDpath
From #TempTable

UNION ALL

Select B.ChildID
    ,B.ParentID
    ,cast(B.ParentID as varchar(max)) + '>' + A.IDpath as IDpath
From CTE A
    Inner Join #TempTable B on A.ParentID=B.ChildID
)
Select Distinct IDpath
From CTE
Where IDpath is not null
```

As far as data, parent ID and child ID are integers between 1-10,000. Some parents have children, some do not (ChildID is null in those cases).

So my output looks like:

ParentID>ID>ID>ID>ID>ID>ChildID (where the ID's in the middle are the children of their parent and then the parent of the subsequent child and so forth).

Comment: Without sample data, expected results, and a well-defined problem statement, this question is quite theorical.

Comment: I found my solution. It's basically "reversing" the CTE. The query above is building the tree (or, it's more like a forest of many trees) back from the leaves to the trunks. By "reversing" how the CTE is assembled, I build from the trunk to the leaves and can identify the branch I want out to the leaves (where the query above only could build from my branch back to the trunk from the leaves (which was not useful to what I wanted to identify). I'll post the solution later when I have more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the code I used to fix my problem to pick ID with the number of 2220 being my "trunk" path and I was able to map this ID out through all of the Parent/Child ID's out to the farthest leafs of my branches of the hierarchy.

Now I'm not an expert at all in SQL coding. Quite frankly, I'm not even good at it so this may not be the best way to fix the issue (or even be a total fix, but given what I was expecting for results, it seems to be working for me).

Now, if 2220 was not a ChildID of another ParentID, I'm not sure if this would work. I may test that later, but as it stands, I'm getting the data I need. However, if this ends up being a problem, I can always do a check and insert it as a ChildID with a ParentID of 0 (as I know all of my ID's are positive integers).

Regardless, this is how I changed up my code to make it work for me:

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
Select 1 as Level
    ,ChildID
    ,ParentID
    ,cast(ChildID as varchar(max)) as IDpath
From #TempTable

UNION ALL

Select Level + 1 as Level
    ,B.ChildID
    ,B.ParentID
    ,A.IDpath + '>' + cast(B.ChildID as varchar(max)) as IDpath
From CTE A
    Inner Join #TempTable B on A.ChildID=B.ParentID
Where Level = 1
    or (Level > 1 and IDpath like '2220%')
)
Select Distinct IDpath
From CTE
Where left(IDPath,4) = '2220'
```

Now, if there is someone with expertise that could comment on the quality of this "fix" and if it's reasonable (or if I'm missing something), I'd appreciate it. I don't want to accidentally poison the masses with a crap fix because of my naivety in assuming that this is a good (enough) fix.

Comment: I was correct in that if the ID I am looking for is not a ChildID of another ParentID, this process fails. Therefore, I fixed this in my data utilizing my proposal above being that my IDs are positive integers, and I added an insert statement to insert any/all IDs that I'm looking for with a ParentID of 0 to mitigate this issue.